# Using foreach loop for `$instance` of form and update array widget iteration

Tags: plugins, plugin-development, widgets

Can I use a foreach loop to iterate over the `$instance` array of a custom widget ? I'm trying to make my code less verbose, but I'm not able to use the loop to escape the inputs and to assign the keys to the relative variables. 
Here is the code I'm testing:

```
public function form( $instance )
{
  foreach( $instance as $key => $val ){
    if( $key === 'text' ){
    $text = isset( $instance['text'] )? wp_kses( $instance['text'], $this->allowed ) : '';
    }
  $key = isset( $instance[$key] ) ? esc_attr( $instance[$key] ) : '';
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure how this makes the code less verbose, but I do know that you shouldn't be using `esc_attr` like that. Escaping should always happen at the very last possible opportunities, on the moment of output. Otherwise you don't know what the appropriate escaping function is. I would advise against doing this, if you want conciseness there are other ways of achieving it without doing this ( to fix your code snippet would require variable variables, which are dangerous, I take it you're trying to avoid `extract` by reimplementing `extract`? )

Comment: @TomJNowell I'm learning about widget creation ( usually I don't work on all my projects with wordpress)  and in the codex example the inputs are implemented using the `esc_attr`. I will remove it if there is a better way to secure the input / output. For the extract function, I can use it, but this means that the inputted values are not sanitized / escaped and it can be a security problem ?

Comment: You should escape yes, just not so early, you escape in the same line you `echo`, escape at the absolute latest possible moment. Sanitise early, but escape late, don't give code any opportunities to modify escaped variables